# How do you say “There are other problems I am still having to resolve.”?

Tags: traduction

**Scenario**:

Due to an outburst he had last year, David (a top lecturer) has been ordered to receive therapy. He is talking to his therapist after a long hiatus.

**Dialogue**

Therapist: It’s been a while. How are you?

David: I am well.

Therapist: Why have you returned to therapy? I thought you overcame your anxiety and depression.

David: There are other problems that I’m still having to resolve. Like, my addictions. I need help some help to defeat them.

**Question**

How do you say “There are other problems I am still having to resolve.” in French?

If the scenario is not clear enough, I do apologise. To avoid ambiguity, David is trying to express that he has been trying to solve these other problems for a very long time and despite having gone to therapy he is still having to face them.

**Answer**

I am struggling to translate “*that I am still having to solve.*” in French.

Is it

« Il y a d’autres problèmes que je dois toujours résoudre. »

?

[image]

[Click here for webpage](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/encore-vs-toujours/)

Answer (score 1):

***Toujours*** can be ambiguous too, as a [link](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/toujours/) from the web page you quote states. For example *Il est toujours en France* might mean that he never leaves France, he is **always** in France.

Therefore, *Il y a d’autres problèmes que **je dois toujours résoudre*** wouldn't be my best choice because it might be understood to imply these problems have no solution.

I'd rather say here:

> Il y a d'autres problèmes qu'**il me reste encore à résoudre**.

Comment: Thank you for your help @jlliagre. I really appreciate! Based on your answer, my scenario may be ambiguous. I have hopefully clearly stated the meaning behind David’s words.